# From Visual Studio (C#) - How to indicate a DEFAULT value for a function while calling a sql server function

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a sql server function that I would like to call from Visual C#. I want to use the DEFAULT value for one of the parameters. What value should I pass from Visual C# to accomplish this?
Thanks,
rkg

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean something like this:

```
 @MySampleSqlParam VarChar(50) = NULL
```

Because it's an optional parameter (it has a default supplied), all you need to do is simply not include that parameter when you call the procedure. So just omit adding the `SqlParameter` to the `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection.

Comment: I tried removing the parameter, but it complains. I know that when you call the funciton on the database side you need to supply the parameter even if you want to use the default value. I removed the parameter from my visual c# program and it complains of missing paramter. But I started working on .NET only from yesterday, so might have made some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourParameter", SqlDbTypes.YourType).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works well when the default value of the parameter is NULL. For example, if the default value is set to 2, this does not work. I know that the function can have the default value as null and then change null to 2, but that may not always be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass a nullable type into the function. Just don't pass the parameter if it's null:

```
public void saveSomething(int? somethingID, string somethingName)
{
     if (somethingID.HasValue)
     {
         //add the parameter
     }         
}
```

And use a default value in the sproc:

```
@SomethingID INT = NULL
```

Obviously, you'll also need to add logic to ignore the condition when the parameter is null.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for optional parameter in SQL. just Google for optional parameter in SQL.

You can create a function with a preset value for the parameter as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnMyFunction
(
@Param1 INT,
@Param2 INT = 2 --Default Values is Set no need to get it from parameter
)
RETURNS ..
```